# Compare multiple rows with previous and subtract if condition is met pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following df:

```
# -- create a dataframe 
list_columns = ['name', 'city', 'country','age']
list_data = [
    ['ana', 'london', 'england',25],
    ['ana', 'london', 'england',22],
    ['sean', 'manchester','london', 20],
    ['sean', 'manchester','london', 23],
    ['dean', 'manchester','germany', 20]
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
```

I want to compare the rows from **name, city** and **country** with previous values and add true if they are the same or false if not.

Finally if the **match** is **True**, subtract **age** rows from previous

Expected result would be:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| name |  city      | country | age| match |result |
| ana  | london     |england  | 25 | False |nan    |
| ana  | london     |england  | 22 | True  |3      |
| sean | manchester |london   | 26 | False |nan    |
| sean | manchester |london   | 23 | True  |3      |
| dean | manchester |germany  | 19 | False |4      |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I know how to compare rows for one column, but I stucked with multiple columns

for one column `df['match'] = df['name'].eq(df['name'].shift())`

I tried
`df['match'] = df(['name ','city','country']).eq(df_alarms(['name ','city','country']).shift())`
but got `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`

Any help is highly apreciated

Comment: Why is the last `match` `True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `shift()` + `any()`:

```
df['match']=df[['name','city','country']].eq(df[['name','city','country']].shift()).any(axis=1)
df['result']=df['age'].sub(df['age'].shift()).where(df['match']).abs()
```

output of `df`:

```
   name     city        country     age     match   result
0   ana     london      england     25      False   NaN
1   ana     london      england     22      True    3.0
2   sean    manchester  london      20      False   NaN
3   sean    manchester  london      23      True    3.0
4   dean    manchester  germany     19      True    4.0
```

**update:**

use `shift()` + `all()`:

```
df['match']=df[['name','city','country']].eq(df[['name','city','country']].shift()).all(axis=1)
df['result']=df['age'].sub(df['age'].shift()).where(df['match']).abs()
#OR df['result']=df.groupby('name')['age'].diff().abs()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not correct because it's not taking all the columns. On line 4 it says True. It should be false because dean != sean and germany != london

Comment: @chris_b according to your expected output in question...I used `any()` if you want to take all column then use `all()`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('name')['age'].diff().abs()
df['match'] = df['result'].fillna(0).astype(bool)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   name        city  country  age  result  match
0   ana      london  england   25     NaN  False
1   ana      london  england   22     3.0   True
2  sean  manchester   london   26     NaN  False
3  sean  manchester   london   23     3.0   True
4  sean  manchester  germany   19     4.0   True
```